# How to get CSS Selector for text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape some date with Selenium (Python) from a website. I want to store the text from the **rollover-s1 lastbooking** and from the **rollover-s2 sr--x-times-last-time** class.

Here is the code from the website:

```
<div data-component="onview-animate" data-anim-type="rollover" data-anim-trigger="mouseenter" class="sr--x-times-booked js_sr_persuation_msg">
    <div class="rollover-s1 lastbooking" rel="300">
3-mal gebucht für Ihre Daten in den letzten 12 Stunden auf unserer Seite
    </div>
    <div class="rollover-s2 sr--x-times-last-time" rel="300">
Zuletzt gebucht  für Ihre Daten vor 2 Stunden
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Python code:

```
first = hotel.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.rollover-s1.lastbooking")
second = hotel.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.rollover-s2.sr--x-times-last-time")
```

The strange thing is that I get the text **3-mal gebucht für Ihre Daten in den letzten 12 Stunden auf unserer Seite** for the first class but I got an empty string "" for the second class.

Do you know what I am doing wrong for the second class?

Comment: You are using find_elements instead of find_element. Any reasons? I may suspect that you have more then one element for the second and one of them would have no value/text

Comment: Hi! How is going? Did my answer help you? Thanks.

Comment: Hi DebanjanB, sorry for not responding! Yes the code is running, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your css selector is already correct. In fact, you could have used shorter ones:

1. ".rollover-s1"
2. ".rollover-s2"

Now to figure out why the 2nd one is showing blank, watch the script in action and see if the 2nd rollover was treated differently from the first one. Is the 1st one currently showing and the 2nd hidden? Are both hidden but the 2nd had never been triggered/shown on the page?

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [React](https://reactjs.org/) element so to locate the element first you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.sr--x-times-booked.js_sr_persuation_msg[data-component='onview-animate'] div.rollover-s2.sr--x-times-last-time"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sr--x-times-booked js_sr_persuation_msg' and @data-component='onview-animate']//div[@class='rollover-s2 sr--x-times-last-time']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```